# tmux command not working at the time of window creation?

Tags: terminal, tmux

I have this command in my `~/.tmux.conf` file:

```
setw -at weechat window-style 'bg=colour235,fg=colour223'
```

I expect the command to tell `tmux` to set the custom background & foreground for any window created with the name `weechat` irrespective of session (i.e. in any session).

But when run the command:

```
tmux -2u new -s myapps -n weechat
```

I get the following error:

```
/home/theone/.tmux.conf:17: no current            [0/0]
/home/theone/.tmux.conf:17: couldn't set 'window-style'
```

And the `window-style` I set in the tmux config. file isn't applied to the window `weechat`.

So I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to clear the error message from the screen, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> and type `:source-file ~/.tmux.conf` for the style to be applied to the Window. (To make the process less cumbersome, I configured a key binding so that when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>, then <kbd>r</kbd>, the config. file is reloaded.)

But I'd like to avoid having to reload the config. file at all for the style(s) to apply, i.e. when I run the command `tmux -2u new -s myapps -n weechat`, I want `tmux` to create the window `weechat` with the colors automatically applied.

Can this be done? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, because global styles applied on config initialization. I would suggest you create key binding that creates named window and applies desired styles to it

```
bind-key C new-window -n weechat \; setw -at weechat window-style 'bg=colour235,fg=colour223'
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize a color style for specific window before the window created in any session. You can add `-vvvv` to your command and check the tmux-server log. I think Sardorbek's answer is good and convenient.